# Error when using smpp-node during bind_transceiver

Tags: javascript, node.js, smpp

Farhadi, i am really having a tough time here getting the smpp-node to work. i get this error when trying your example.

{"command_length":16,"command_id":2147483657,"command_status":13,"sequence_number":1,"command":"bind_transceiver_resp"}. I tried to do   and i get

this.command_id = commands[command].id;
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at new PDU (/Users/tinyiko/MyCode/MyApp/node_modules/smpp/lib/pdu.js:21:37)
    at PDU.response (/Users/tinyiko/MyCode/MyApp/node_modules/smpp/lib/pdu.js:80:9)
    at Array. (/Users/tinyiko/MyCode/MyApp/sendmessage.js:12:52)
    at Session._extractPDUs (/Users/tinyiko/MyCode/MyApp/node_modules/smpp/lib/smpp.js:62:40)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:424:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:418:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:174:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)

This is the code i am trying...

```
var smpp = require('smpp');
var session = smpp.connect('bulksms.2way.co.za', 2775);

console.log(session);

session.bind_transceiver({
  system_id: '673293',
  password: 'passwordxxx'
}, function(pdu) {
    if(pdu.command_status == 13){
    console.log("session" + pdu.command_status);
    pdu.response();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(pdu));
    }
  if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
    // Successfully bound
    console.log('bound bind_transceiver')
    session.submit_sm({
        destination_addr: '0847849574',
        short_message: new Buffer("Hi, Froxtel interview SMS/email has been sent by company only. Its not any related to freshersworld. U can contact directly company or call 08688805062/3.Please ignore the word freshersworld in sms/mail.regards Froxtel team.","utf8"),
        source_addr:'FROXTL',
        registered_delivery:1,
        data_coding:0,

    }, function(pdu) {

        if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
            // Message successfully sent
            console.log(JSON.stringify(pdu));
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on SMPP v5.0 Specification command_status=0x0D means:

> Bind Failed. A generic failure scenario for a bind attempt. This may
>   be due to a provisioning error, incorrect password or other reason. A
>   MC will typically return this error for an invalid system_id,
>   system_type, password or other attribute that may cause a bind
>   failure.